# A simple implementation of a mutable String in C

Tags: c, strings

The following code implements a simple interface to operate on mutable* `String`s in C. It is composed of two files: one for the structure definition and the available operations, and the other with the actual implementation.

*This can be inexact, as only adding characters to the end is implemented.

Any comments on coding style and improvements are greatly appreciated.

**String.h**

```
#ifndef __STRING_H__
#define __STRING_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

typedef struct {
    char *data;
    int length;
    int blocks;
} String;

String * string_create();
void string_dispose(String *str);

bool string_empty(String *str);
void string_append_char(String *str, char c);

char * string_get_all(String *str);
char string_get(String *str, int pos);

int string_find(String *str, char c);

#endif /* __STRING_H__ */
```

**String.c**

```
#include "String.h"

/** Create a String */
String * string_create() {
    String *ans = calloc(1, sizeof *ans);

    if (ans != NULL) {
        ans->data = malloc( BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof *(ans->data) );

        ans->length = 0;
        ans->blocks = (ans->data == NULL) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    return ans;
}

/** Free the memory associated with a String */
void string_dispose(String *str) {
    if (str != NULL) {
        free(str->data);
        free(str);
    }
}

/** Is the String empty? */
bool string_empty(String *str) {
    if (str == NULL) return true;
    if (str->length == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

/** Add a character to the end of the String */
void string_append_char(String *str, char c) {
    if (str != NULL) {
        if (str->length == str->blocks * BLOCK_SIZE) {
            char *new_str = realloc( str->data, BLOCK_SIZE * (str->blocks + 1) * sizeof *(str->data));

            if (new_str != NULL) {
                str->data = new_str;
                ++(str->blocks);
            }
        }

        if (str->length < str->blocks * BLOCK_SIZE) {
            str->data[str->length] = c;
            ++(str->length);
        }
    }
}

/** Get a C-String with the proper null-terminator */
char * string_get_all(String *str) {
    char *res = NULL;

    if (str != NULL) {
        res = malloc((str->length + 1) * sizeof *str->data);

        if (res != NULL) {
            memcpy(res, str->data, str->length);
            res[str->length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return res;
}

/** Get a character at a given position in the String */
char string_get(String *str, int pos) {
    char res = '\0';

    if (str != NULL) {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < str->length) {
            res = str->data[pos];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

/** Get where the first occurrence of a character in the String is */
int string_find(String *str, char c) {
    int pos = -1;

    if (str != NULL) {
        pos = 0;
        while (str->data[pos] != c) ++pos;

        if (pos == str->length) pos = -1;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

This is a test file that uses some of the core methods implemented in a `String`. This file is called **test_string.c**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "String.h"

int main() {
    String *str = string_create();

    char i;
    for (i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        string_append_char(str, i);

    char *cstr = string_get_all(str);

    printf("%s\n", cstr);

    int pos = string_find(str, 'f');

    printf("Character 'f' occurs at position %d.\n", pos);
    printf("Reading from the String, we get \"%c\".\n", string_get(str, pos));

    free(cstr);
    string_dispose(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unsafe loop

This loop in `string_find()` is unsafe since it could read past the end of your buffer:

> ```
>     while (str->data[pos] != c) ++pos;
> ```

You should add an additional check like this:

```
    while (pos < str->length && str->data[pos] != c) ++pos;
```

#### Short circuit error conditions

Rather than doing this:

> ```
>  if (str != NULL) {
>      // Rest of function indented
>  }
> ```

it would be easier to read if you rewrote it like this:

```
if (str == NULL)
    return NULL;

// Rest of function, not indented
```

#### Other things

Your reallocation strategy will lead to \$O(n^2)\$ behavior when appending to long strings.  You might want to double the allocation instead of adding a fixed amount.

You might want to use `size_t` for your sizes and lengths instead if `int`, because an `int` might overflow at 32KB on some platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'll take into account all your suggestions. I actually found the first issue while testing - I am now using `strchr` for finding, but didn't know why it was failing. I'll post a revised version soon.